# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar ficheros con Python?

Tags: python

Me gustaría borrar unas imágenes que se me van descargando en la misma carpeta de un programa codificado en Python.

La cosa sería que tras guardar y hacer lo que sea con la foto, quiero borrarla. Como se guarda con un nombre distinto de cada vez, no puedo decirle un nombre concreto. Entonces, pensé en borrar por el tipo de archivo, pero no funciona.

He hecho esto:

```
dir = "../telegram-bot-peisou/"
dirr = os.listdir(dir)
for item in dirr:
    if item.endswith("*.jpg"):
        os.remove(dirr+item)
```

He intentado definirlo en un método también, pero con resultado similar.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/updates.py", line 277, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bot_v1.2.1.py", line 32, in my_event_handler
    edit_photos(foto)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bot_v1.2.1.py", line 62, in edit_photos
    os.remove(dirr, item)
TypeError: remove() takes at most 1 positional arguments (2 given)
```

edit_photos es el metodo que he definido. Poniendolo en la raiz del programa, me dice esto:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bot_v1.2.1.py", line 57, in <module>
    os.remove(os.path.join(dirr, item))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

Comment: es que te dice que `remove()` solo recibe un argumento y le das dos. En efecto, con `os.remove(item)` debería haber suficiente. Dicho lo cual, por consola podría decir `rm *.jpg` y ya lo tendrías hecho.

Comment: Si le paso directamente eso me dice que no lo encuentra, como le defino el path entonces? o que borre sobre la misma carpeta? 
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/bot_v1.2.1.py", line 61, in edit_photos
    os.remove('*.jpg')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '**.jpg'

Comment: ah vale que `item` solo contiene el nombre del fichero. Entonces sería algo así como `os.remove(dirr + item)` para que se genere la ruta completa del fichero.

Comment: edito el post con mi codigo editado, no me da error, pero no borra nada, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, acepta rutas relativas? o tengo que darle path absoluto?

Comment: podrías hacer algo de debugging imprimiendo algún `print` aquí y allá. Fíjate además que `string.endswith()` admite cadenas fijas, mientras que tú le estás dando "*.jpg". Lo que deberías hacer es `item.endswith(".jpg")` y ya está.

Comment: Si lo hago asi como dices ahora me dice que no puede concatenar lista con str,
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
si quieres pongo prints, pero vamos poco mas hay que ver creo yo,

Comment: ah vale que `dirr` es una lista. Supongo entonces que tienes que concatenar con `dir` (con una R, ya podrías elegir variables más representativas :P)

Comment: Ya la verdad jajaja, pero para probar fui a lo rápido, ahora si :) si quieres redacta tu respuesta y te la doy por valida. Muchísimas gracias ^^ que fallo mas tonto dios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código dices:

```
dir = "../telegram-bot-peisou/"
lista_ficheros = os.listdir(dir)
for fichero in lista_ficheros:
    if fichero.endswith("*.jpg"):
        os.remove(lista_ficheros + fichero)
```

Donde he modificado el nombre de las variables para hacerlos más representativos.

Entonces lo que estás haciendo en el bucle `for` es iterar sobre un listado. Una vez allí, quieres detectar qué ficheros tienen la extensión "jpg" y, en tal caso, eliminarlos.

Bueno, pues hay dos problemas:

- `if fichero.endswith("*.jpg"):`
  Esto está mirando si el nombre del fichero termina exactamente en "*.jpg". Entiendo que te querrías referir al globbing que hiciera coincidir todos los ficheros con la extensión "jpg". Sin embargo, así como está descrito busca todos aquellos que tengan como parte final _exactamente_ "*.jpg":

  ```
  >>> 'hola.jpg'.endswith('*.jpg')  # no encuentra la cadena ".jpg" porque antes no va el literal '*'
  False
  >>> 'hola*.jpg'.endswith('*.jpg')  # encuentra el literal "*.jpg"
  True
  ```

  Por tanto, debes decir:

  ```
  if fichero.endswith(".jpg"):
  ```
- `os.remove(lista_ficheros + fichero)`

  Aquí el uso de una variable cuyo nombre lía con el otro (`dir` y `dirr`) ha provocado que uses el que no toca. En este caso, como vimos en los comentarios, sería:

  ```
  os.remove(dir + fichero)
  ```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @fedorqui, ha quedado funcional 100%